# How to use Task.WhenAll with NPoco fetchAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, npoco

I'm trying to use Task.WhenAll. It's not working though because fetchAsync seems to get triggered when i declare classesTask. Any ideas? Using .Net framework 4.7.2 and NPoco

```
var classesTask = scope.FetchAsync<ClassModel>();
var competitionsTask = scope.FetchAsync<CompetitionDto>();

// Wait for all tasks to complete concurrently
await Task.WhenAll( classesTask, competitionsTask);

// Access the results directly
var classes = await classesTask;
var competitions = await competitionsTask;
```

Comment: Why do you need Task.WhenAll, we can await the FetchAsync call right?

Comment: To improve performance @SoorajNair

Comment: If FetchAsync is triggered immediately, try to wrap them in Task.Run(() => scope.FetchAsync<ClassModel>());

Comment: I'm guessing that for whatever reason this `FetchAsync` method isn't actually async. Might need debugging further into the source code.

Comment: @Charlieface I think you're right.